# What do the vectors $ (1, 0, 0), (0, 1, 0), (0, 0, 1)$ correspond to geometrically?

Tags: vector-spaces

Would I be correct in saying that they correspond to all points in $\mathbb{R}^3$? Or a line in $\mathbb{R}^3$?

Answer (score 1):

On their own they're simply vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. However, if you were to take all linear combinations of these vectors

$$c_1(1,0,0) + c_2(0,1,0) + c_3(0,0,1) \text { where } c_1,c_2,c_3 \in \mathbb{R}$$

Then this would give you the entire space of $\mathbb{R}^3$. In more technical language, $\beta = \{(1,0,0), (0,1,0),(0,0,1)\}$ is a basis for $\mathbb{R}^3$ and therefore, it generates $\mathbb{R}^3$.

Comment: To briefly add a bit more about the vectors geometrically, they are also all orthogonal to each other - each one is at right angles with the others.

Comment: And they're also normal, so they're an orthonormal basis.

Answer (score 0):

They are just vectors in $\mathbb{R}^3$. They do not correspond to all points nor do they make a line.